# Multiple Solr instances + Tomcat + Zookeeper

Tags: tomcat, solr, apache-zookeeper, solrcloud

i am trying to get external Zookeeper running along with multiple Solr instances combined with one Tomcat server on a windows machine. I have been prepared everything to have both solr instances being accessible through tomcat. The next step would be to upload Solr instance configuration (single cores of every instance) to zookeeper.

Unfortunately i only do find jetty examples or single solr instance @ tomcat. Maybe somebody does know, how to upload the configuration to my Zookeeper instance?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?
1. Multiple Solr instances on _different_ tomcat servers linked to zookeeper.
OR
2. Multiple Solr instances on _the same_ tomcat server, linked to zookeeper. (Quite a bit odd case)

Answer (score 0):

The deployment in Tomcat is quite similar, except from :

- In solr.xml you will have to add 'hostPort="8080"' in  tag
- You will have to start Tomcat with the zkHost parameter, and all other parameters that normally you launch with java command (boostrap_conf, numShards...):

  ```
  -DzkHost=z1.com:2181,z2.com:2181,z3.com:2181
  ```
- First launch ZK instances and then Tomcat.

There is a guide here (it's not perfect because it covers only some cases and it's not very lisible, but it can help you) : http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrCloudTomcat